# My 11 year old son is out of control and no1 can seem to help. What can I do?

Tags: behavior, siblings, adoption

This has been my nightmare since he has been 5 just getting progressively worse. He is 11. I have had the police at my home 3 times in 6 days. He has been to the psych ward twice in a years time. This week alone he has beat up his brother twice, tackled his little sister and slammed her face off the ground, and punched me on two different occasions.

The police won't help. The hospital won't take him, they say its a police matter. His doctor said he is "beyond her scope." They can't put him in placement without a court order, can't get a court order without a record, and can't have a record if the police won't help!

The school doesn't want him there cause he has stabbed a couple kids, one with a spork and the other with a pencil. He had an aide but he punched her in the stomach knowing she was pregnant (she quit). He requires private transportation for school because he kicked a little girl in the face, punched a few other girls and boys.

He has also broken his older brother's arm in 2 places, and kidnapped his baby sister - before taking off with her he punched out my windows.

He is one of 5 kids. We are all scared and nobody is willing to help. There has to be something. tTis can not be my life forever!

Comment: What country do you live in? this would help giving better advice on how to deal with authorities. Also what methods of discipline have you tried?

Comment: Hi Misty, as A.bakker asked, we need some details - what jurisdiction are you in, why do the police say they won't help, do you have a reference from the psych ward who could help progress treatment/custody etc.

Comment: Please provide helpful details. If he was in a psych ward, he's in the psychiatric  system. How are they failing you/your son? Did you call the police when he broke his brother's arm?  In the Emergency Room, we call Crisis Intervention when a sibling is injured. Did the school press charges for the attacks/have Children&Youth/Crisis Intervention been called? What was the outcome? (Btw, *treating* this *is* beyond the scope of of the average doctor. He needs a psychiatrist to help treat him, which happens in a psych facility.) And a *criminal* type Conduct Disorder *is* a police matter.